# Construct a Modulo Multiplication Table

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Consider a `n x n` multiplication table and replace each item with its remainder of division by `n`. For example, here is a `6x6` table and its "modulo 6" structure: (The last column and row are ignored since both are null)

```
1  2  3  4  5  6   |   1 2 3 4 5  
2  4  6  8 10 12   |   2 4 0 2 4  
3  6  9 12 15 18   |   3 0 3 0 3  
4  8 12 16 20 24   |   4 2 0 4 2  
5 10 15 20 25 30   |   5 4 3 2 1  
6 12 18 24 30 36   |
```

Now it is evident that the multiplication table modulo n is symmetric and can be reconstructed by one of its triangular quadrants:

```
1 2 3 4 5
  4 0 2
    3
```

### Challenge

Given a positive integer N, print the upper quadrant of multiplication table modulo N. Assume that there is no restriction on the width of string in your output environment. The alignment of numbers shall be preserved. This means, the output should look like a part of a **uniform** product table, where the cells have equal widths. So for example, if we have a two-digit number in the table, all single-digit entries are separated by two spaces.

### Rules

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test cases

```
N = 1:
// no output is printed

N = 3:
1 2

N = 13:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
   4  6  8 10 12  1  3  5  7  9
      9 12  2  5  8 11  1  4
         3  7 11  2  6 10
           12  4  9  1
              10  3
```

[<sub>Sandbox</sub>](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22426)

Comment: Is the centering necessary or can answers return `[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,0,2],[3]]` for example?

Comment: @Wzl the shape is one of the requirements of the challenge. that's why I mentioned the spacing in case of multiple-digit numbers

Comment: thanks, I should have read it more closely. While it may be too late to change, I personally think it is already a reasonable challenge to extract the triangle and the formatting just makes it more cumbersome.

Comment: Can we have trailing whitespace?

Comment: In the N=13 case, can we have single-space between the first 3 columns?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing sure, and in reply to Adám, that's against the rules

Comment: `+1` for a somewhat interesting challenge,`-1` for the unnecessarily cumbersome output format.

Comment: Can the colums be right aligned like so: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYzJDcNADAP/W8WUYGmvuJ6k/xbWEYXAfsRB@JLA4byeaxk4VGjQYcCEB@xgG2aYs0FBxFAXhWOadQ2Cfv/Jkb@HuOfAgm5CM@VzhGOKcOnDzZlyuUPZ0i2UOw5pqlB@c4nyD/c1ax0 "dc – Try It Online")

Comment: @Shaggy I thought the challenge without this specific output format would be a pretty trivial and boring one. As in multiply and then modulo? meh...

Comment: _The alignment of numbers shall be preserved_ Is it OK to use more spaces than necessary as long as the alignment is preserved? If not, it should be specified more clearly.

Comment: @Jonah Isn't that *left* aligned?

Comment: Yeah I meant to ask if left aligned is ok, as the example is right.  Unclear to me if that particular detail of alignment matters

Comment: Your `N = 13` output is missing an all-space column on the left.

Comment: Should this question be tagged as [tag:ascii-art]?

Comment: @Adám seems not, the question says "all single-digit entries are _separated_ by two spaces". Nothing suggests there should be a leading space.

Comment: @tsh The question also says "the cells have equal widths". If there is not leading space, then the first column/cell does not have the same width as the others. The question's example for N=13 is not consistent with this requirement, though.

Comment: Please add `N = 10` and `N=11` as test cases.

Comment: Can we supply a function that returns a list/vector/array of strings?

Comment: btw, 4  6  8 10 12  1  3  5  7  9 -> 4+9=13, 6+7=13, 8+15=13, 10+3=13, 12+1=13. this holds true for all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
Ｅ⊘θ⪫Ｅ⊖θ◧⎇‹›ιλ‹⁺ιλ⊖θＩ﹪×⊕ι⊕λＩθωＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY27DsIwDEV/JerkSmVAjIwg8VCROvQHrMTQSG4CTlrE14eolNdk@fhcX92haI@cUiPWRTjhFfbIIxm4lZU6eusmtiUt1JOL86FBU9M5QkviUB5QUwiwE8JIArZSnJ2JNTyEN/h/UmaywZA7vRnYQ2t7CnBwX8dm43fnT@SVvk8l7hK7GRSqyHOd0nKVFiM/AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: Trailing space. Explanation:

```
  θ                                 Input `n`
 ⊘                                  Halved
Ｅ                                   Map over implicit range
      θ                             Input `n`
     ⊖                              Decremented
    Ｅ                               Map over implicit range
        ⎇‹›ιλ‹⁺ιλ⊖θ                 If this entry is wanted
                      ⊕ι            Row value
                     ×              Multiplied by
                        ⊕λ          Column value
                    ﹪               Modulo
                          Ｉθ        `n` as an intger
                   Ｉ                Cast to string
                            ω       Otherwise the empty string
       ◧                     Ｌθ     Pad to length of `n`
   ⪫                                Join with spaces
                                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: Accepted your answer since it is the shortest one without trailing spaces

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
’×þ%ɓoU¥⁺GµḶ⁶ẋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4oCZw5fDviXJk29VwqXigbpHwrXhuLbigbbhuov///8xMw)

Outputs a bunch of trailing whitespace. Used the `’×þ%` trick from [hyper-neutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226784/66833), so be sure to give them an upvote

### How it works

```
’×þ%ɓoU¥⁺GµḶ⁶ẋ - Main link. Takes N on the left
’              - Decrement
 ×þ            - Create a multiplication table for all integers from 1 to N-1 and 1 to N
   %           - Mod each by N. This leaves a trailing row of zeros. 
                 Call this table T

           Ḷ   - Yield [0, 1, 2, ..., N-1]
            ⁶ẋ - Yield that many spaces for each
                 Call this list of spaces S

    ɓ     µ    - New dyadic chain f(S, T):
       ¥       -   Group the previous 2 links into a dyad g(S, T):
     o         -     For each row in S and T, replace the first N elements of the row in T with spaces,
                      where N is the number of spaces in the row in S
      U        -     Reverse each row
        ⁺      -   Do it again
         G     -  Format it as a grid and output
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
’×þ%µJ’⁶ẋoUµ⁺G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zD0w/vUz201QvIfNS47eGu7vzQQ1sfNe5y////v6ExAA)

I stole the idea to use logical OR to avoid needing to trim and re-pad the lists from caird. Go upvote [their solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226785/68942) too, please.

```
’×þ%µJ’⁶ẋoUµ⁺G   Main Link; accepts x
’                x - 1
 ×               using multiplication
  þ              create a product table (this does x - 1 by x)
   %             modulo x
----µ---------   start a new chain on this table
     J           range over length (1, 2, ..., N)
      ’          decrement (0, 1, 2, ..., N - 1)
       ⁶ẋ        repeat " " by ^
         o       vectorized logical OR; basically fills the lower left triangle with spaces
          U      reverse each row
     ------µ⁺    duplicate the last chain, so this fills the lower left and flips horizontally twice, thus cutting the list to just the upper triangle
             G   format as grid
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>60</sup> 55 bytes

```
1}."1,/"2@((' ',.' ',":@,.){~(<|.)@(>/~)*1+#|>:*/>:)@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/LSgMxFIb3eYqPcZFJncnMyVxqgx0GBFfSha8gLdaNGxeCta8@JkdFpIGEk@@/hLwshbcHthFLRUtMu/bcPT7cL/LpC6maIsxlabGVz0cR58q7j3N5e/JuLqfm7FZyfXWa4qqZopuPfnFm//T8ygH5Hmxd21/UXaLxEklnjNm/H9@sNTu26R6NQIAOehhghDXcwAZpEUGCQcUx48ySXTQxqHeTdTQQtGtQo6ir/xHRwFpxyF3S/iloss8V6W/8W@lBuuUL)

<sup>-5 thanks to xash</sup>

I thought this would be a good challenge for J, and the essence of the problem is, but the formatting details destroyed me here.

Comment: Tried my luck at it, got it down to [55b](https://tio.run/##ZY/LSgMxFIb3eYqPcZFJncnMyVxqgx0GBFfSha8gLdaNGxeCta8@JkdFpIGEk@@/hLwshbcHthFLRUtMu/bcPT7cL/LpC6maIsxlabGVz0cR58q7j3N5e/JuLqfm7FZyfXWa4qqZopuPfnFm//T8ygH5Hmxd21/UXaLxEklnjNm/H9@sNTu26R6NQIAOehhghDXcwAZpEUGCQcUx48ySXTQxqHeTdTQQtGtQo6ir/xHRwFpxyF3S/iloss8V6W/8W@lBuuUL), but sadly nothing groundbreaking.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) >= 4.1.0, <s>165</s> 152 bytes

```r
\(n,`/`=sprintf){z=outer(1:n,1:n,\(x,y)(x*y)%%n[2-(pmin(y,n-y)>=x)]);z[is.na(z)]="";z[]="%%%ds"/nchar(n-1)/z;cat(apply(z,1,paste,collapse=" "),sep="
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvBasMwEETv/QqzINgtqxq1txjlR5JAhGtRgbsWkgKWQr7ddVroYZh5MC9t3m7@JmMJi6Dwtb/aHFOQ4une7HIrU0JzEH7m/7dyJVxfKyklp3eN8TsIVhZd6WhXutDQTiG/icNGFwuw415Kqc8MvYxfLqFoQ30bRlfQxThXbGw4ulwmHpd5djFPFjogzlO08AL02PySMHRBOnMwH3R/qqC1PstZgAODPnZ/@1cBGjyGXfsB)

An anonymous function that takes an integer and prints the triangle to STDOUT. The TIO link replaces `\` with `function` since TIO is on an earlier version of R.

Thanks to @RobinRyder for saving 5 bytes, and @KirillL for saving a further 8!

Comment: Nice idea using `NA`s! [This](https://tio.run/##PYzRqsIwEER/JSwUdi@bi/W@WeKPaB9CaTBQtyGJ0ETut9dWwYeBGWbOxNWZ1T1kyH4WFHpWMz/yGLE9Ce/6dgsXwuWnUNPI5agx3L1gYdGFzmahnrp68elXLFbqDSjYcm9SiF6yw2BTHg8IDfDdLijDzcZtSKwgAXGlbrAZbQhTwcotv/c8zNNkQxr3O@I0BgNXAfpf3RzRKy@qPbV/9NxZ0FpfZavZM@iz@vg3A9Q59Bv2Ag "R – Try It Online") builds the `NA`s in the same way at -2 bytes.

Comment: And you can gain [3 more bytes](https://tio.run/##PYvBCsIwEETvfkVZKOzKRqzeLPFHtIdQGgzUbUgiNBG/vVYFDwMzzHthsXqxD@mTmwSFnkVPjzQEbE7Cn/y/mTPhvM1U13I5KPR3J5hZVKaznqmjtlxc3InBQp0GWGenow9OkkVvYhr2CDXw3cwo/c2ElSOGCMSF2t4kNN6PGQs3/MW5n8bR@DhoqFYoDl7DBui12Cmgq5xUzak50vOjglLqKlcBdgzqXP36VwFqLbpVewM "R – Try It Online") by removing extra spaces and changing `"\n"` into an actual new line.

Comment: A couple of extra savings: 1) You can use `nchar(n-1)` as padding size because it is the max number in the table 2) Assigning `sprintf` to operator allows cheaply reusing it to form `%?s` string too, for [166 in R 3.x](https://tio.run/##PYvBasMwEETv/QqzINgtqxq1txjlR5JAhGtRgbsWkgKWQr7ddVroYZh5MC9t3m7@JmMJi6Dwtb/aHFOQ4une7HIrU0JzEH7m/7dyJVxfKyklp3eN8TsIVhZd6WhXutDQTiG/icNGFwuw415Kqc8MvYxfLqFoQ30bRlfQxThXbGw4ulwmHpd5djFPFjogzlO08AL02PySMHRBOnMwH3R/qqC1PstZgAODPnZ/@1cBGjyGXfsB). However, I also found an [entirely different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229144/78274)

Comment: @KirillL. Thanks! Like your answer too +1

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB/Octave, 117 bytes

```matlab
function f(n)
r=1:n;m=num2str(mod(r'*r,n));s=(nnz(m(1,:))+2)/n;for k=1:n
m(k,1:k*s-s)=32;disp(m(k,1:(n-k)*s))
end
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctBCoMwFATQfU7hzj9WKd9AF4ZcoXcoakBCfkqiXfTyKSrFxWzezMRxfX3mUtwm47pEqRwJVLI8iAlWttDnNVGIE6W6Sa0AJlsS@VIgbgfg1uMuxsVU@f2kAvmWB9/kLsPq3kxLftOJJJ1HkwE1y7SnHGX9tFxDOWKoP@gD9AWPAx4X8DlhjfID) This prints out quite a lot of trailing whitespaces. If we sacrifice 2 bytes to replace `k=1:n` with `k=1:n/2` the empty lines won't be printed though.

Despite my efforts to find more elegant solution using `triu` function (takes upper triangle of square matrix) this stayed the shortest solution I came up with.

Ungolfed/explained:

```matlab
function f(n)
r=1:n;
m=num2str(mod(r'*r,n)); % modulo table transformed to char array
s=(length(m(1,:))+2)/n; % how many characters takes up one number
for k=1:n
  m(k,1:k*s-s)=' ';     % replace first k-1 numbers with spaces
  disp(m(k,1:(n-k)*s))  % print first n-k numbers
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES8), 92 bytes

Expects the input as a string.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>++k>n/2?'':(h=i=>++i>n-k?`
`:(i<k?'':i*k%n+'').padStart(n.length+1)+h(i))``+g(k))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBDsIgEEDRfe9hZpAUU01cNIUewgtAWgoIGZqWeH2UraufvP82H3MuR9hLT3m1dZOVpEIno1ScR0W3@wwwopehQVDUx1l3esQwxXbCNV6IAzCxm/VVzFGQRLLkiucD4x4DY1pzh7G1LpnOnKxI2eGG8ATGuj8bHj@sXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>113</s> 96 bytes

```python
def f(n):d=range(1,n);[print(*[f"{['',v*x%n][v>=x<=n-v]:{len(str(n-1))}}"for v in d])for x in d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZBCsIwEAXQvacIBelMaReh4KIaLxKyEJLRgvyWNIRI6dkj4lu99ZNeC8ZafRAlBJ68iQ88A@kefLVrnJGos9Lstm373JUznM13U24GQ3bT/g6gLUXCoJmPo5ElqqxmKO/49/J/FbrwSUiPXL8)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 35 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{1↓⍕d⍪' '@{∨∘⌽⍨∘.>⍨⍳d}⍵|∘.×⍨⍳d←⍵-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rwUdvkR71TUx71rlJXUHeoftSx4lHHjEc9ex/1ghh6diC6d3NK7aPerTUggcPToSKP2iYAxXQNa/@ngZl9j7qaH/WuedS75dB640dtEx/1TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf/TFAy5dHV1udIUjKC0MZQ2gdKmUNrQAMaA6TA0BgA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; N is `⍵`:

`d←⍵-1` let `d` be N minus one

`⍳` indices one through N

`∘.×⍨` multiplication table

`⍵|` that modulus N

`' '@{`…`}` replace with spaces **at** locations indicated by:

`⍳d` indices one through `d`

`∘.>⍨` greater-than table

`∨∘⌽⍨` logical OR with its own mirror image

`d⍪` prepend a row of `d`s (to size columns widths right)

`⍕` format to character matrix

`1↓` drop the first row

Comment: If you don't mind some trailing whitespace, `(⌈d÷2)↑` can be replaced with `¯1↓`.

Comment: @ovs Oh, I misread OP's answer to caird and me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
’<þa⁶oU$o’×þ%ƊG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0ybw/sSHzVuyw9VyQfyDk8/vE/1WJf7////DY0B)

Also outputs a ton of trailing whitespace

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 109 bytes

```r
n=scan();m=(1:n%o%1:n%%n)[,-n];m[l<-lower.tri(m)]="";m[l[,n-1:n]]="";write.table(format(m,j="r"),,,F,r=F,c=F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMgEAD/Igi7sAZCb0336ifEgw0WUtwVtkKeb5teBmYYm1P5sxcF3IRhvavv/qJXTBQ0b5LaI7R@VluGHSCY2bmrJtLwO/PfTztGXUZ5tgqvblIGCL3ZmUMiimQcaeeIc73NLw)

A full program with some hacking around the built-in formatting/printing functionality to achieve the desired result. Here is the printing statement with all the formatting options ungolfed:

```r
write.table(format(m,justify="right"),quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

If printing the numbers left-aligned is allowed after all, then we can save a few extra bytes by removing right-justification.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ù▼åU☻┐≈◘E╝ÖBñGRR
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=971f865502bff70845bc9942a4475252&i=13%0A1%0A3&m=2)

about as short as I could get it. centering the stuff took more bytes than i expected.

### Explanation

```
vc{*x%K{itiT|>Jm|Cm
vc                  decrement and duplicate input n
  {   K             cross-product map ranges (1..n-1) and (1..n-1)
   *                multiply the numbers
    x%              mod n
       {       m    map each row to
        itiT        iteration number trimmed from both sides
            |>      right align each number
              J     join with spaces
                |C  center
                  m print joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `CM`, <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
ƛ⁰ɽƛ⁰ɽ*⁰%;$in(ṪḢ);ƛƛ:L⁰Lεð*p;Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=CM&code=%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%C9%BD%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%C9%BD*%E2%81%B0%25%3B%24in%28%E1%B9%AA%E1%B8%A2%29%3B%C6%9B%C6%9B%3AL%E2%81%B0L%CE%B5%C3%B0*p%3B%E1%B9%84&inputs=13&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ⁰ɽƛ⁰ɽ*⁰%;$in(ṪḢ);ƛƛ:L⁰Lεð*p;Ṅ    
ƛ                ;                For each n in range(0,input):
 ⁰ɽƛ     ;                         Generate the table: For each in range(1,input):
    ⁰ɽ*                            Multiply by range(1,input) to make a table.
       ⁰%                          Mod(input) everything
          $i                       Make a triangle: Get the nth row of the table
            n(  )                  Repeat n times:
              ṪḢ                    Remove the head and tail

                                  Align the numbers:
ƛ                                 For each row of the triangular table:
 ƛ        ;                        For each number in that row:
  :L⁰Lε                             Take difference of length(input) and length(number)
       ð*p                          Prepend that many spaces
           Ṅ                       Join each row on spaces
```

`C` centers the output, and `M` makes implicit ranges start from 0.

Improvements welcome.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-lm`, 96 bytes

-7 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
w,i,j;f(a){w=log10(a)+2;for(i=0;i++<a;puts(""))for(j=i;j+i<=a;)printf("%*d",j++-i?w:w*i,i*j%a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLCoMwFET3fkUICLkmgnXpNfQjuu0maCM3PlFLoOKvN00Lnc0ZzsA0edc0IXhFyqEVBg6vh7m7FLHKEu28CtIFkpS1weW5b4JzgK92mtBJqrVBWFaadit4mrVcOSlzuvrKZ6Qoc6kBPEPc2WhoEnAkLOZ3HF3PNCswomZlpBW9lADsf3ij16NiaXufuOoBkzO8GzuYbgv5MH4A)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>106</s> 103 bytes

-3 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
w,i,j;f(a){for(w=2,i=a;i/=10;w++);for(;i++<a;puts(""))for(j=i;j+i<=a;)printf("%*d",j++-i?w:w*i,i*j%a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCoMwEETvfsUSELImUuvRNfQjeu0laFM2UivWEqj47Wly6FwG3gwzQ/0YhhiDZu3JSYu7e60ymFazscQnc24oKIWUMbFSvaXls72lEIiZecPkFfepjcvK8@akKKtRaK9UzZfQhYo1V760SEdMOTwtzxL3ApLyQmYTGGgoWQ9tcien9InwH7zy995BOd5moSek4og/)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Without trailing/leading spaces/newlines (**26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
L¨Dδ*s%εNF¦¨]DZg>jðδÛ˜õK.c?
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv8wNWFiMWX//0zCqETOtCpzJc61TkbCpsKoXURaZz5qw7DOtMOby5zDtUsuYz///zEz) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VS6KP33ObTC5dwWrWLVc1v93A4tO7Qi1iUq3S7r8IZzWw7PPj3n8FZvvWT7/0p6YYe26fyPNtQx1jHTMTSOBQA).

With leading spaces and trailing spaces/newlines (**20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
L¨Dδ*s%εNF¦¨]DZg>j.c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59AKl3NbtIpVz231czu07NCKWJeodLssveT//w2NAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VS6KP33ObTC5dwWrWLVc1v93A4tO7Qi1iUq3S5LL/m/kl6YzqFtOv@jDXWMdcx0DI1jAQ).

**Explanation (of the longer version):**

```python
L               # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ¨              # Remove the final value to make the range [1, input)
                # Create a multiplication table matrix:
  D             #  Duplicate this list
   δ            #  Apply double-vectorized:
    *           #   Multiply
     s          # Swap so the (implicit) input is at the top of the stack
      %         # Modulo each value in the matrix by this
ε               # Map over each row:
 NF             #  Loop the (0-based) map-index amount of times:
   ¦¨           #   And remove the leading/trailing items
]D              # After both the inner loop and map: duplicate it
  Z             # Get the flattened maximum of this matrix (without popping)
   g            # Pop and get its length
    >           # Increase this length by 1
     j          # Prepend spaces in front of each integer up to that length+1,
                # and then join every row together to a single string
       δ        # Map over each inner string:
      ð Û       #  Strip leading spaces
         ˜      # Flatten this list (`δ` unfortunately wraps the strings in lists in the
                # legacy version..)
          õK    # Remove all trailing empty strings
            .c  # Centralize this list of strings
              ? # And output it without trailing newline
```